# WebResource reporting 404 file not found

Tags: asp.net, download, webresource.axd

I'm working on a system that embeds various JS and CSS resources in the project dll, and access them using WebResource.axd. This all works fine locally, but if I download and install the app from our nightly build server, all our WebResources report a 404 error.

We initially though it was because the downloaded zip file was blocked, and for a while, unblocking the downloaded zip before extracting did work, however, now, nothing seems to work.

Swapping the downloaded dll with the one created locally makes the WebResources work, so it sounds like something is going on with the dll (either on the download server, or during the download process).

Anybody got any ideas what it might be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I managed to find the culprit myself, which was that the Modified Date timestamp on the DLL's was set to the future (our build server is in a timezone one hour ahead of ours), so for some reason WebResource wasn't picking them up.

Hope this helps someone in the future.

Comment: This is definitely the reason for the problem (I have the same one). I wonder if anyone has found a workaround? For instance, it would be great if we could _tell_ ASP.NET that we _know_ the modified date will be off by an hour.

Answer (score 0):

This normally occurs if you are using AJAX/3rd party controls. Most probably it is not a problem of missing WebResource.axd but some other reference / resource pointer is missing. Try debugging using the information provided on [this site](http://blogs.telerik.com/blogs/posts/07-03-26/debugging_asp_net_2_0_web_resources_decrypting_the_url_and_getting_the_resource_name.aspx)